# Taking into account navigation bar and tab tar when adding layout constraints in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a tableView in my app, and in Xcode I added the constraints to start at the beginning and finish at the bottom of the main view. However, the navigation bar and the tab bar hide the beginning and the footer of the tableView.

Do you know what I need to do to discount the size of these bars so the tableView shows properly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Added this to my viewWillApper method:

```
//makes sure UITableView won't be under tob/bottom bars
    if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) {

        [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];

    }
```

Comment: You could try using `self.navigationController.topLayoutGuide` and `self.navigationController.bottomLayoutGuide`

Comment: @user3529796 can you please elaborate more on your answer?